# If the viewbag has any value,it has to display it in a new tab.otherwise it has to display an alert in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i click a button it has to take the value in particular row table and send it to the mvc controller.In MVC,i am using viewbag.If the viewbag has  details ,that has to be displayed in a new tab.otherwise it has to display an alert box in a same page ..not in the new tab..i have written some code.it is working.it will display those things in a new tab.if viewbag doesn't have any value it should display an alert box in a same window.that's not working.can you help me ??

thanks in advance

Comment: How about you start by showing us your code?

Comment: Not able to understand the flow .

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments your questions needs more details for clarification, though if I have understood your problem you can do this,

==> DO NOT make AJAX call on viewbag click.

==> Check that is any item is there in cart on viewbag click, and if empty giver error alert else open new tab.

==> now on new page on it's load event make AJAX call and get data.

This should do the trick.

Hope this helps.